# What is the correct way to "end" a request from express/connect middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

Assuming I have middleware such as this;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var host = "example.com";

    if (req.host !== host) {
        res.redirect(301, host + req.originalUrl);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

What sort of rules do I need to abide by here?

1. Should I be calling `res.end()`? (or does `res.redirect()` do this for me?)
2. Should I be calling `next()`? (or does connect detect the request has ended and exit cleanly?)
3. Assuming that I *should* be calling `next()`, I guess that means *I* can potentially be receiving requests to my middleware which may have already been ended by other middleware higher in the chain; how do I protect myself against this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. `res.redirect()` indeed calls `res.end()` itself;
2. You should call `next()` if your middleware isn't the end point; in the case of generating a redirect, it *is* an endpoint and `next()` shouldn't be called, but if `req.host === host`, you need to call `next()` to move the request up the chain to other middleware/routes;
3. A request doesn't get ended, a response does. And when it does, it will end the middleware chain so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Something to note is that if you have other processing to do you can still call next, however be mindful that you've sent a response so the response object is finished and pretty much a variable for post-response processing.

This is useful where you want to send a response and THEN do other slower operations like communicating with other servers to track stats or send emails, or push things onto a queue or talk to a database or etc., so really ending an express request/response chain is when you don't call anymore middleware and it gets garbage collected.