# Node.js: TypeError: req.end is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm getting a req.end is not a function, when it works elsewhere in the code. From googling, I've seen that perhaps the global req variable got lost?

But I'm not using any other variable named `req`......

This only happens within the first name and last name check loop.....

```
app.post('/createaccount', function(req, res){

    req.end()

}); //end app.post(createaccount)
```

Comment: Whats `req.end` supposed to do? Did you mean `res.end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method called `end()` in the `Request Parameter`. `end()` is available only for the `Response`.

```js
res.end(); // not req.end()
```

Comment: how do I end a request early then? Like I don't want the rest of my code to run on the server side.

Comment: a request doesn't get end, But a response does... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571779/what-is-the-correct-way-to-end-a-request-from-express-connect-middleware

Comment: @Evan Use a `return` statement.